# Implementation of thread-safe vector

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, vectors

I have implemented a thread safe vector, based on std::thread and std::vector. I am new to many of the patterns used in threading and was wondering if there's a more efficient way the locking can be implemented? Also I'm not sure what the best name is to give variables that just get stored right away (i.e. `in`).

Here is SafeVector.hpp

```
#ifndef SAFEVECTOR_HPP
#define SAFEVECTOR_HPP

#include <vector>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <string>

class SafeVector {
public:
    SafeVector() : vec(), mut(), cond() {}
    SafeVector(const SafeVector& orig) : vec(orig.vec), mut(), cond() {}
    ~SafeVector() {}

    void insert(std::string in, const int index);
    void push_back(std::string in);
    std::string& operator[](const int index);
    std::vector<std::string>::iterator begin();
    std::vector<std::string>::iterator end();
    std::vector<std::string> toVector();

private:
    std::vector<std::string> vec;
    std::mutex mut;
    std::condition_variable cond;
};

#endif /* SAFEVECTOR_HPP */
```

Here is SafeVector.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include "SafeVector.hpp"


void SafeVector::insert(std::string in, const int index)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mut);
    vec[index] = std::move(in);
    cond.notify_one();
}

void SafeVector::push_back(std::string in)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mut);
    vec.push_back(std::move(in));
    cond.notify_one();
}

std::string& SafeVector::operator[](const int index)
{
    return vec[index];
}

std::vector<std::string>::iterator SafeVector::begin()
{
    return vec.begin();
}

std::vector<std::string>::iterator SafeVector::end()
{
    return vec.end();
}

std::vector<std::string> SafeVector::toVector()
{
    return vec;
}
```

Currently, these are the only functions I need to use on vectors but if I decide to implement more, I'm assuming the rest would be done in the same way.

Comment: What is the purpose of condition variable here?

Answer (score 3):

We probably want to be able to move-construct, so as well as this constructor:

> ```
> SafeVector(const SafeVector& orig) : vec(orig.vec), mut(), cond() {}
> ```

We probably want also:

```
SafeVector(SafeVector&& orig)
  : vec{std::move(orig.vec)},
    mut{},
    cond{}
{}
```

I'd recommend being able to construct from a standard vector:

```
SafeVector(std::vector vec)
  : vec{std::move(vec)},
    mut{},
    cond{}
{}
```

Since we always default-initialize `mut` and `cond`, we could declare their initializers in the class definition, removing the need to have them in the constructors' initializer lists.

There's no need to specify an empty destructor - just let the compiler generate it.

I think we probably want one or more assignment operators.

Big question: how can we safely use iterators we get from `begin()` and `end()`?  There's no way for client code to lock the mutex until it's finished using the iterators.